# Running DNS Server to circumvent NAT-Loopback issue

Tags: networking, dns, nat, loopback, owncloud

First I want to say that I probably read everything that there is on the internet regarding the problem.

And the problem is that I can not access my owncloud over doc.selfhost.eu if I am in the same network. But I can access it from inside the network over its internal IP (192.168.2.200) and from outside the network over doc.selfhost.eu.

My setup: 
A home server running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon which is supposed to be for media and to run owncloud.

The server is connected to a Speedport 723v which doesn't support NAT Loopback. Ports 80 and 443 are forwarded and for dynamic DNS I have an account on selfhost.de which I entered in the router settings.

On my Windows 7 machine (which I'm trying to access the server from) I entered 192.168.2.200 (the servers internal IP) as DNS.

In Mint I disabled network manager (in fact I removed it) and I am now using interfaces.

Not a solution would be to change the hosts files of all the clients (on unrooted androids this isn't even possible).

**Question:**

1. What would I have to change to access my owncloud from the internal network over the external IP?

*/etc/network/interfaces*

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers doc.selfhost.eu 8.8.8.8
```

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

In */etc/dnsmasq.conf* this is the only thing I added:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=192.168.2.200
address=/doc.selfhost.eu/192.168.2.200
```

*/etc/dnsmasq.d/doc.selfhost.eu* (read somewhere to create this)

```
address=/doc.selfhost.eu/192.168.2.200
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       doc-desktop
192.168.2.200   doc.selfhost.eu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Owncloud settings in
*/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php*

```
'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
0 => '192.168.2.200',
1 => 'doc.selfhost.eu',
  );
```

Apache configuration
In */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* everything is pretty standard. I only added:

```
ServerName doc-desktop
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/owncloud.conf*. No changes in *sites-available*, no linking.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.200:80>

#### Redirect to port 443 ###
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
#### End of Redirection configuration ###

DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/
<Directory /var/www/owncloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.200:443>
####Configuration for SSL #####
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
#### End of SSL Configuration ####
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/
<Directory /var/www/owncloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In case it comes up.
from server:

```
dig doc.selfhost.eu

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> doc.selfhost.eu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49046
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;doc.selfhost.eu.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
doc.selfhost.eu.   0       IN      A       192.168.2.200

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 26 02:35:15 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

From client inside network (with cygwin):

```
dig doc.selfhost.eu

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3 <<>> doc.selfhost.eu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29482
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;doc.selfhost.eu.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
doc.selfhost.eu.   0       IN      A       192.168.2.200

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.200#53(192.168.2.200)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 26 02:37:32     2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

I hope this is everything. 
Thanks.

This question comes from here since it was off-topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337258/running-dns-server-to-circumvent-nat-loopback-issue

Answer (score 2):

**External Solutions**

> What would I have to change to access my owncloud from the internal network over the external IP?

Unfortunately, having never personally encountered a home router that didn't support NAT Loopback (also known as [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)), I can't provide a concrete answer on how to access it with anything *external*.

**Other Solutions**

- You may want to look further into [Split-horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) or using [PFSense NAT Reflection](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can%27t_I_access_forwarded_ports_on_my_WAN_IP_from_my_LAN/OPTx_networks) as suggested in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/992699/can-not-access-web-domain-from-local-computers).
- You may also want to look at this [supported list of NAT Loopback supported routers from OpenSimulator.org](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers) if you decide to buy a new one.
- It may also be possible to upgrade to custom firmware e.g. Tomato or DD-WRT, but I would investigate this process thoroughly before attempting anything.

---

**A DNS-based Solution**

Assuming your goal isn't more complicated than accessing your media server from the internal network with a human-readable domain and you are willing to configure BIND DNS, you can try to make a [pseudo-domain](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pseudodomain) available to your network as well.

This pseudo-domain would potentially allow you to access your local server at something like `server.own` on the internal network. This fake [Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (TLD) *ex*. `.own` can essentially be anything you want.

I would suspect this should work even with the NAT Loopback issue.

**Using a Pseudo-domain**

The simplest arrangement is to have one computer on the network provide DNS. The biggest potential drawbacks to this arrangement are:

- You will likely need to make sure that your router is pointing to the server running BIND.
- The computer serving as your DNS server will need to be on for this (and your net connection) to work.

[image: Router DNS Entries Pointing To Local DNS Server]

Also, while likely less important in this case, running a BIND service that provides access to both internal and external networks can be somewhat risky. Generally, you should *not* mimic a [public TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) like `.eu` unless you know what you are doing. If you want to keep the `doc.selfhost` prefix rather than something else, that's fine, but you should pick a different *unused* extension (e.g. `doc.selfhost.own`).

**Apache and Owncloud**

Once enabled, you will need to set up Apache (your pseudo-domain will likely be a VirtualHost) and Owncloud to properly respond to queries and serve the appropriate content (e.g. Owncloud).

**Working Examples**

Below are some working examples of how to configure the main files in BIND to provide pseudo-domain services.

Note that I am *not* covering all of what you might need to do to get BIND itself working, so there may be some extra steps not explicitly mentioned here. *Also note, these examples are technically for recent versions of* [BIND 9 on Windows](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) (BIND 9.10+).

The actual contents of **db.rev.10.txt** and **db.example.own.txt** shouldn't need modification between Windows and *nix. The bigger obstacle is making sure the **named.conf** entries appear in the right files on non-Windows platforms and that **db.rev.10.txt** and **db.example.own.txt** appear in the correct *nix directories.

---

*Note that when using Redhat-based distros, there are subtle differences between them and Debian/Ubuntu/Mint.*

---

Assuming you are okay with all of this, here are the basic working examples. This is essentially a caching DNS configuration, if it matters.

1. Get BIND set up and working. I'll wait. =)
2. **named.conf** — Edit **named.conf.** (roughly) as given below. On Windows, all entries are in "named.conf" (located in the BIND "etc" directory). On modern *nix, these entries are often split over several files. Also make sure to include any proper "rndc-key" and "control" entries as needed.

   *ex. named.conf*

   ```
    # Our basic options -- where do we find our zone files, etc.?
    # On *nix, options likely need to go in "named.conf.options"

    options {
        directory "Path\to\zones";      # On *nix it's / not \ of course
        allow-transfer { none; };       # disable zone transfers by default

        # We restrict access to recursion to avoid security issues, etc.
        # You can change IPs as required.
        #allow-recursion {192.168.1.0/24;}; 

        # "localnets" is a special ACL in BIND
        allow-recursion {"localnets";};

        # We are using named.root, so forwarders are disabled.
        # forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
    };

    # Current versions of named.root/db.cache -- ftp://ftp.internic.net/domain/
    # *nix likely uses named.root (Redhat/Fedora) or db.cache (Deb/Ubu/Mint) 
    # This file does need periodic updating (perhaps twice a year)

    zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "named.root";      # On Windows, place in your BIND "zone" directory
    };

    # Local domain where "example.own" is whatever domain you want
    # On *nix, these zone definitions likely need to go in "named.conf.local"

    zone "example.own" IN {
        type master;
        file "db.example.own.txt";   # On Windows, place in your BIND "zone" directory
        allow-transfer { none; };
    }; 

    # Local loopback interface so our local domains work
    # The digits are the local lan prefix in reverse
    # Note that /16 subnets use only two digits e.g. 128.10 for 10.128.xxx.xxx

    zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
          type master;
          file "db.rev.10.txt";     # On Windows, place in your BIND "zone" directory
          allow-transfer { none; };
    };

    # ### Any "rndc-key" and "control" statements go here ### 

    # End of named.conf
   ```
3. **db.rev.10.txt** — Our Reverse zone file. Add PTR records for each physical server referenced in your Forward zone file (e.g. **db.example.own.txt**). In this example, we are assuming as single media server at `10.0.0.3` we wish to call `example.own`.

   *ex. db.rev.10.txt*

   ```
    ; BIND reverse data file for a local loopback interface
    ; The domain used should be a listed 'zone' in named.conf 

    $TTL 86400                ; Default TTL
    @   IN SOA  example.own.    admin.example.own. (
                 2015071301      ; serial
                 10800           ; Refresh period
                 3600            ; Retry interval
                 604800          ; Expire time
                 86400 )         ; Negative caching TTL

    ; The number before PTR is the last octet of the IP address
    ; for the device to map (e.g. 10.0.0.3). For /16 subnets,
    ; this is the last two digits e.g. "8.9" for "128.10.in-addr.arpa" (10.128.9.8)

        IN  NS  ns1.example.own.
        IN  NS  ns2.example.own.
    3   IN  PTR example.own.
   ```
4. **db.example.own.txt** -- Our Forward zone file. In this example, we are assuming as single media server at `10.0.0.3` we wish to call `example.own`. You can add MX and CNAMEs as well, of course. If you add additional servers (e.g. `media IN A 10.0.0.4`), add the appropriate PTR record to your Reverse zone as well (e.g. **db.rev.10.txt** → `4 IN PTR media.example.own`)

   *ex. db.example.own.txt*

   ```
    ; We are using our reverse DNS to provide name server services
    ; Enables use of http://(www).example.own on our local network

    $TTL 86400              ; Default TTL
    @   IN SOA  ns1.example.own.    admin.example.own. (
                2015071322  ; serial
                10800       ; Refresh period
                3600        ; Retry interval
                604800      ; Expire time
                86400 )     ; Negative caching TTL

    @       NS  ns1.example.own.

    ns1             IN A        10.0.0.3        ; This entry is ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY - Use an IP
    ns2             IN A        10.0.0.3        ; Secondary Name Server Prefix/IP (Required 2nd Name Server - backup - IP or domain)

    example.own.    IN A        10.0.0.3        ; A Record for the basic domain name
    www             IN A        10.0.0.3        ; A Record for the www prefix
   ```

**Odds and Ends**

- Make sure to update the Serial on both your Forward and Reverse zones each time you make changes to them.
- **Likewise, make sure to "reload" bind after making ANY changes to you BIND config files.** As a general thought, you probably want to back any originals up as well before tinkering.
- Assuming everything is set up correctly, every capable device (including Android) on the network *should* be able to access `example.own` without further configuration (i.e. like the regular net).
- Note that that if you are using Chrome, you need to append a trailing slash in the address bar (e.g. `example.own/`), otherwise you may be redirected to Google search. [This requirement will likely not be changed in any future versions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qO6_tUich3k).
- While for more traditional setups, these two articles for [Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [Centos 7 (Redhat)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-centos-7) illustrate some of the differences in configuring BIND between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just some clarifications:
selfhost is a service which gives you a domain name which in my case is `doc.selfost.eu` and resolves it to an IP. Others get `othername.selfhost.eu`. I don't have any influence on the naming, except of the `doc`. 
The important thing is not that I can access my server using something human readable but I need to access the server from *everywhere* with *one* domain. I don't care if it is an IP or a string. I don't want to change the address in the owncloud client every time I log in. 
I'll see how far I get with your tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this issue for the last month since buying a brand new $180 Linksys WRT1200AC router. I also have a dynamic IP account which enables me to access my home network from the road. I've done a ton of research, like you have. But something as simple as making sure my sites are online is now impossible. I even created a Python proxy server on the Google cloud so I could see these sites; however it eventually stopped working for some unknown reason.

My environment is Windows but the issue is identical. My sincere advice is to simply buy a new router and save yourself a lot of frustration and misery. I'm now shopping for one myself, but it's proven to be very difficult to find a new router that supports NAT loopback. I have not discovered a way to get around this problem otherwise. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too sure, to understand all aspects of this and I stumpled in here more accidentally. For my own infrastructure, I solved this using iptables rules to redirect the intrenal requests to the internal servers - but I am using a linux machine as my firewall. Anyway looks useful to read this link:
[Accessing a DNAT sever from the local LAN using the public IP address](http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/iptables)